# Manually fire full screen button click event for Video tag in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a simple video tag in my HTML5 page. I am not showing the controls for the video tag.
Check the code below:

`<video width="320" height="240" >
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

Is there any way to fire the full screen button click event and make the video run in full screen mode.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Initiated by a user click on an element

```
 function makeFullScreen(divObj) {
       //Use the specification method before using prefixed versions
      if (divObj.requestFullscreen) {
        divObj.requestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (divObj.msRequestFullscreen) {
        divObj.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (divObj.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        divObj.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }
      else if (divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else {
        console.log("Fullscreen API is not supported");
      } 

    }
```

for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Activating fullscreen mode**

Given an element that you'd like to present in fullscreen mode (such as a `<video>`, for example), you can present it in fullscreen mode by simply calling its `requestFullscreen()` method; this method is implemented in Gecko as `element.mozRequestFullScreen()`, in Trident as `element.msRequestFullscreen()` and in WebKit as `element.webkitRequestFullscreen()`.

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)